# Correlation of $X^3$ and $Y$

Tags: probability, statistics, correlation

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are two uncorrelated random variables and the PDF of them are both even. Can we expect that $X^3$ and $Y$ are also uncorrelated? Thanks.

Comment: If independent, yes.  Uncorrelated - maybe.

Answer (score 4):

We cannot expect $X^3$ and $Y$ uncorrelated.

Like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent), choose $X\sim N(0,1)$ (standard normal), and

$$
Y=
\begin{cases}
X & \text{ if } |X|\le c\\
-X & \text{ if } |X|> c\\
\end{cases}
$$
where $c\approx1.54$ is chosen such that $E[XY]=0$

Then it is easy to prove that $Y\sim N(0,1)$, so both PDFs are **even**, $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, and furthermore:

$E[X^3Y]\approx -2.2\ne E[X^3]E[Y]=0$, so $X^3$ and $Y$ are correlated.

Answer (score 2):

No. We definitely can not expect that.

Consider $X$ and $Y$ has the following pmf on four points $\{ (-1,-1), (2,-1), (1,1),(-2,1)\}$: $P_{(-2,1)}=P_{(2,-1)}=1/6$  and $P_{(1,1)}=P_{(-1,-1)}=1/3$.

Then clearly we have $X,Y$ are uncorrelated, with zero mean and even marginal distributions. And what's more, this distribution is symmetric with respect to the origin. But $X^3,Y$ are correlated:

$$E[X^3 Y] = 2 \ne E[X^3] E[Y] =0$$

If worried about this is PMF not PDF, you could substitute each point into a uniform square of radius $0.1$.

Comment: @JetfiRex If $X\in \{-1,1\},Y\in \{-2,2\}$, how can the joint distribution assign 1/6 mass to each of the four elements in $X\times Y$?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Please read my post carefully: first, the supporting set is not $\{-1,1\}\times\{-2,2\}$; second, two of them has probability $1/3$ rather than $1/6$.

Comment: @JetfiRex Thanks, misread. Perhaps it may be a bit more clear to write it something like $(X,Y)=(-1,2),(1,-2)$ with prob etc.? Or specify supports first?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Thank you for your suggestion! I will fix that